# Move UIView left to right while they move down the screen

Tags: ios, uiview, quartz-graphics

I am trying to create an iOS app with blocks floating down the screen(UIViews). I have them floating down the screen but I also want the user to be able to move them on the x axis as they are falling. I tried to do it with the code below but they just fall and don't move left to right. My problem is I am trying to move it with my finger left to right as it is already moving town the screen. How can I adapt the code below to work?

Note: I was able to move the views left to right without them moving down the screen and I was able to move them down the screen without moving them left to right. The problem arises when I combine both.

ANIMATION FOR Y AXIS

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:letView.speed];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

letView.layer.frame = CGRectMake(letView.layer.frame.origin.x, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, letView.layer.frame.size.width, letView.layer.frame.size.height);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

ANIMATION FOR TOUCH

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    //Goes through an array of views to see which one to move
    for (LetterView * view in _viewArray) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, touchLocation)) {
            dragging = YES;
            currentDragView = view;
            [currentDragView.layer removeAllAnimations];
        }
    }
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if (dragging) {
        CGPoint location = touchLocation;
        currentDragView.center = CGPointMake(location.x, currentDragView.center.y);
    }
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    dragging = NO;
    [self checkForCorrectWord];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:currentDragView.speed];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    currentDragView
    .layer.frame = CGRectMake(currentDragView.layer.frame.origin.x, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, currentDragView.layer.frame.size.width, currentDragView.layer.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged to check that your 'CGRectContainsPoint' is matching? Are the views in _viewArray all direct subclasses of self.view?

Comment: I was able to move the views left to right without them moving down the screen and I was able to move them down the screen without moving them. The problem arises when I combine both.

Comment: How is the animation down the screen working? Your touch handling code is removing all animations from the touched view layer. Your question only really gives details on half the information.

Comment: I would like to not stop the animation moving down the screen if possible.

Comment: Next, what have you tried to combine them? Stopping and staring a new animation? Leaving the existing animation? Something else?

Comment: I tried to just have the animation with them falling down and moving them left to right but when that didn't work I though well maybe if I stop the animation for moving it down then start it again after the user moves it left to right it might work. This however did not work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28198/discussion-between-wain-and-bdgapps)

Answer (score 2):

I've got a demo project that shows you how to make a "boat" animate down the screen in an s-curve, like this:

[image]

The solution I use is to make a *keyframe animation* (actually it's a keyframe animation that forms part of a grouped animation, but you might not need the rest of the grouped animation: it is the keyframe animation that makes the curved path shape). Perhaps you could adapt what I'm doing, modifying it to your own purposes?

The code is available for download here:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/ch17p501groupedAnimation

It is discussed in detail in my book. Keyframe animations generally:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_keyframe_animation

This particular example:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_grouped_animations

Comment: My problem is moving it with my finger as it is moving down the screen.

Comment: Sorry, but if you're moving it with your finger you wouldn't be using an animation at all. You would just make the view follow the finger (trivial with a UIPanGestureRecognizer).

Comment: Or are you saying you want the view to be touchable while it is being animated??? That is a *very* difficult problem, because during animation a view is not actually located in the spot where you see it.

Comment: Also, any change in the view's position while its position is being animated would kill the animation.

Comment: that is why i stop the animation and start it again but it didn't work.